# How to remove route in tomtom maps sdk?

Tags: java, android, routes, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

Is there a way to remove the route without clearing the markers? Using function clear() is really bad.

```
 tomtomMap.clear();
    route = null;
    origin = null;
    destination = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a function clearRoute() that do not clear the markers.

Take a look at the API reference

https://d221h2fa9j1k6s.cloudfront.net/downloads/mapssdk/APIReferences/JavaDocMap_2.4.376/index.html

I was able to test the function in my project and verified that it works.

tomtomMap.clearRoute() should solve your problem.

Regards!

Comment: Thank you so much,  you might want to check this too :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905837/how-to-lock-the-position-of-marker-and-visibility-properties-in-tomtom-maps-sdk